# Visual Studio Code editor: Disable IntelliSense for CSS files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to write some CSS for an exercise. When I attempt certain Emmet shortcuts, for example many two letter ones like mt - margin-top, the IntelliSense prompt overrides Emmet. I could dismiss the prompt, but I'm trying to reduce keystrokes here.

Is there a way to disable IntelliSense for particular files or even files types? Or perhaps another solution I have not thought of?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's too late but I found the answer:

Put this in your settings.json:

```
"[css]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false    
}
```

Normaly now, you wont get intelliSense suggestions in your .css files.